# How to get path of php.ini?

Tags: php, apache-2.2, php.ini

I have currently 3 `php.ini`S files in my /etc/php5 path.
tree:

```
./php5_
./php5_/cli
./php5_/cli/conf.d
./php5_/cli/php.ini
./php5_/apache2
./php5_/apache2/conf.d
./php5_/apache2/php.ini
./php5_/conf.d
./php5_/conf.d/suhosin.ini
./php5_/conf.d/mysql.ini
./php5_/conf.d/mysqli.ini
./php5_/conf.d/gd.ini
./php5_/conf.d/pdo.ini
./php5_/conf.d/mcrypt.ini
./php5_/conf.d/curl.ini
./php5_/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
./cli
./cli/conf.d
./cli/php.ini
./apache2
./apache2/conf.d
./apache2/php.ini
./conf.d
./conf.d/memcache.ini
./conf.d/suhosin.ini
./conf.d/mysql.ini
./conf.d/mysqli.ini
./conf.d/gd.ini
./conf.d/pdo.ini
./conf.d/mcrypt.ini
./conf.d/memcached.ini
./conf.d/curl.ini
./conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
```

but I still feel that there is something wrong.
I tried to make some syntax errors in all php.ini files, tried to restart apache and it restarted successfully. What's wrong? How do I get path to REAL php.ini I should edit to be able to see changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the web, create a simple php page that has the following

```
    <?php
    phpinfo();
    ?>
```

It will show all the ini files parsed

Answer (score 6):

From your command line, just run php --ini:

```
[sandro@mercury ~]$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/extensions.ini
```

Comment: and when I use cli, does it apply to browser (apache) access, too ?

Comment: Unless you've managed to setup multiple php's on the same server running your apache server, yes.  I actually had to setup a server using php4 and php5 years ago, and it's a glorious pain.  You'd have run into this question far sooner if you had such a setup ;) edit: sreimer's answer is probably best to know for certain what the server's referencing as far as your php install is concerned

Answer (score 2):

You can check it with:

```
# php -i | grep "php.ini"
```